# Email alert from unix Server

Tags: unix

I am using below mentioned script for sending disk usage email alert from unix server but system is not generating email alert.

```
    #!/bin/bash
CURRENT=$(df / | grep / | awk '{ print $5}' | sed 's/%//g')
THRESHOLD=70
if [ "$CURRENT" -gt "$THRESHOLD" ];then  
mail -s imran2233@gmail.com<<EOF   
$CURRENT%
EOF
fi
```

Comment: Do you miss a heredoc sign like `<<EOF`? See https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html

Comment: i update row as  mail -s imran2233@gmail.com << EOF but still following error 0403-057 Syntax error at line 6 : `<' is not matched.

Comment: Spaces are really important: `< <` is wrong (space in the middle), while `<<` (no spaces in between) is correct.

Comment: In actul no space but << EOF but still same error 0403-057 Syntax error at line 6 : `<' is not matched.

Comment: Ensure the script is executed by bash and not ksh; ensure the file is not CRLF line-terminated and there are no trailing spaces, and post the *real* content of your script.

Comment: Done,Please check above code,now following errors  warning: here-document at line 5 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: I tried your script and it works, but I had to delete leading spaces in first line, and trailing spaces on the line containing "<<EOF". I understand that perhaps your posted code shows different spaces from the real script, but I suspect there is a problem with spaces, and your last error confirms this. Double check! And read carefully https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html

Comment: After removing spaces now following error--The flags you gave make no sense since you're not sending mail.

Comment: Congratulations! This is a step forward. You should check the correct syntax for the mail(1) command installed on your system, but the heredoc problem seems to be gone.

Answer (score 0):

Actually now your mail command is missing the subject.

`mail -s "my subject" imran2233@gmail.com`